# How to Open a link (web page) in fullscreen mode, javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, video, fullscreen

simply I need to open a new page in fullscreen.

So, users press a button and then a video (hidden on main page) is open in fullscreen and start to play. When user press button to close fullscreen or press "esc" key, video will pause, fullscreen is closed and iframe is not visible...

I'm try to get this demo works, but with no results.
Also I can make it works only if I open only the video element, not iframe...

```js
const fullscreen   =  document.querySelector('.playnow');
const video        =  document.querySelector('#myvideo');

fullscreen.addEventListener('click', toggleFullScreen);

// Create fullscreen video button
function toggleFullScreen() {

    if(video.requestFullScreen){
        video.requestFullScreen();
    } else if(video.webkitRequestFullScreen){
        video.webkitRequestFullScreen();
    } else if(video.mozRequestFullScreen){
        video.mozRequestFullScreen();
    };
    video.classList.remove("d-none");
}
```

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.video-container{
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position:relative;
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1616485828923-2640a1ee48b4?ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=3150&q=80);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position: center;
}

#myvideo{
 
}

.d-none{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-container">
  <button class="playnow">Open Video in Fullscreen Mode</button>


  <video width="100%" autoplay id="myvideo" class="d-none">   
      <source src="//d2zihajmogu5jn.cloudfront.net/big-buck-bunny/master.m3u8" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
</div>
```

I've tried:

- https://gomakethings.com/how-to-play-a-video-in-full-screen-mode-when-its-thumbnail-is-clicked-with-vanilla-js/  (better demo, but video still visible after fullscreen is closed...)
- https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/html5-fullscreen-api/

But no appreciable results.

Thank you, Luca

Comment: Does your `toggleFullScreen` function get called?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try something like that.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('button')
const screenWidth = window.screen.availWidth;
const screenHeight = window.screen.availHeight

function openFullscreenWindow() {
  window.open('https://github.com', '_blank', `width=${screenWidth},height=${screenHeight}`)
}

btn.addEventListener('click', openFullscreenWindow)
```

```html
<button>Open fullscreen</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a found a solution reading this post on medium: https://medium.com/@roidescruzlara/controlling-the-full-screen-mode-cda0fae4c4f2

And now I can use it as I need.

Thank you so much.

```js
var currentWindowHeight = window.innerHeight;
var element = document.getElementById("container");
var btn = document.getElementById("btn-screen-mode");
var film = document.getElementById("film");
var isFullScreen = false;

window.addEventListener("keydown", useCustomFullScreen.bind(this));
window.addEventListener("resize", isExitingFullScreen.bind(this));

/**
* Gets available exitFullscreen method 
*/
function getRequestFullScreen() {
  return (
    element.requestFullscreen ||
    element["mozRequestFullscreen"] ||
    element["msRequestFullscreen"] ||
    element["webkitRequestFullscreen"]
  );
}

/**
* Gets available requestFullscreen method 
*/
function getExitFullscreen() {
  return (
    document["webkitExitFullscreen"] ||
    document["msExitFullscreen"] ||
    document.exitFullscreen
  );
}

/**
* Prevents browser to enter the default fullscreen mode and uses the custom fullscreen method
*/
function useCustomFullScreen(event) {
  if (event.key === "F11") {
    event.preventDefault();
    toggleFullScreen();
  }
}

/**
* Detects if the browser is exiting fullscreen mode when window resize
*/
function isExitingFullScreen() {
  if (isFullScreen && currentWindowHeight >= window.innerHeight) {
    isFullScreen = false;
    currentWindowHeight = window.innerHeight;
    
    // Do your full screen mode stuff 
    updateBtn();
  }
}

/**
* Update button appearance according to the current screen mode
*/
function updateBtn() {
  if (isFullScreen) {
    btn.classList.remove("enter-fullscreen");
    btn.classList.add("exit-fullscreen");
    element.classList.remove("d-none");
    film.play();
    return;
  }
  
  btn.classList.remove("exit-fullscreen");
  btn.classList.add("enter-fullscreen");
  element.classList.add("d-none");
  film.pause();
}

/**
* Toggles the fullscreen mode using available fullscreen API
*/
function toggleFullScreen() {
  if (!isFullScreen && getRequestFullScreen()) {
    getRequestFullScreen().call(element);
  } else {
    getExitFullscreen().call(document);
  }

  currentWindowHeight = window.innerHeight;
  isFullScreen = !isFullScreen;
  
  // Do your full screen mode stuff 
  updateBtn();
}
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#container video {
   width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.intro{
  width:100%;
  height:100vh;
}

.intro video{
  max-width:100%;
  height:auto;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.d-none{
  display:none;
}

#btn-screen-mode {
  
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.enter-fullscreen {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;bottom:0;left:0;right:0;
  margin: auto;
  z-index:2322333;
  background-image: url(https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/1674/PNG/512/expand_111060.png);
}

.exit-fullscreen {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  position: absolute;
  top:20px;
  right:20px;
  z-index:2322333;
  background-image: url(https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/1673/PNG/512/collapseoutline_110793.png);
}
```

```html
<div class="intro">
  <button id="btn-screen-mode" class="enter-fullscreen" onclick="toggleFullScreen()"></button>
  <video autoplay loop muted playsinline="true" webkit-playsinline="true">
              <source src="https://test-videos.co.uk/vids/bigbuckbunny/mp4/h264/1080/Big_Buck_Bunny_1080_10s_1MB.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>


<div class="container d-none" id="container">
      <button id="btn-screen-mode" class="exit-fullscreen" onclick="toggleFullScreen()"></button>
      <video loop playsinline="true" webkit-playsinline="true" id="film">
            <source src="//d2zihajmogu5jn.cloudfront.net/big-buck-bunny/master.m3u8" type="video/mp4">
      </video>
      
</div>
```