# Open a link in fullscreen

Tags: javascript, html, browser

I'm trying to open a link in full screen. I took the code from here.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_element_requestfullscreen

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="openFullscreen();">Open Link in Fullscreen Mode</button>

<a href="https://www.yahoo.com" id="mypagelink"></a>

</body>
</html>

<script>
var elem = document.getElementById("mypagelink");

function openFullscreen() {
  if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
    elem.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) { /* Safari */
    elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) { /* IE11 */
    elem.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
}
</script>
```

Here is the Codepen link.
https://codepen.io/mochi777/pen/xxQqZGZ

It opens in fullscreen but just black window. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It does seem to work, you only have to click the black screen to open the website

Comment: your link is empty so it appears black on full screen. it might be clickable but maybe you want to use an `iframe` for this?

Answer (score 0):

The API you are using is designed to make the targeted **element** full screen. That element is an `<a>` element with no content inside it so when it is made full screen it appears to be blank.

You seem to be under the impression that it will load the link target (the URL in the `href` attribute) full screen. That’s a mistaken impression.

Browsers don’t provide an API to open URLs full screen. It is something that can only be done by the page itself in response to the user interacting with it.

A couple of possible work arounds are:

- Open the URL in an iframe and make the iframe full screen. This will require that the URL does not use X-Frame-Options or a CSP to ban you from placing it in an iframe.
- Use the `window.open` API to open the URL in a new window and set the dimensions equal to the height and width of the screen. This will display at least some browser chrome as you can’t eliminate things like the title bar entirely.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to make it work with iframe.

Answer (score -3):

Hello Toshi i think this answer will help you achieve your requirement

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66790295/13987286

here is the code

```
const btn = document.querySelector('button')
const screenWidth = window.screen.availWidth;
const screenHeight = window.screen.availHeight;
function openFullscreenWindow() {
  window.open('https://github.com', '_blank', `width=${screenWidth},height=${screenHeight}`)
}
btn.addEventListener('click', openFullscreenWindow)

<button>Open fullscreen</button>
```

Comment: for more detail for window.open you can refer this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/34610532)

Comment: ok got this brother. answer updated, Thanks for suggestion.